# Why is my rendered object faceted?

Tags: rendering

[image]

I don't know why it's not smooth. Can someone please help me? I'm a beginner in Blender. I saw this tutorial online but the output is not the same as his.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be unique and identifying and summarize what the issue is, so that visitors can at a glance understand broadly what your post is about from the question list. Please use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors will see, and weights on their decision to open your question or not, so the number of answers you might get depends heavily on it.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is simple. Select your object and then right click and click shade smooth. I would reccommend you see a complete beginner tutorial series.[image]

Comment: Thank You Sir, I will. Sorry for asking dumb questions.

Comment: @Zomel no need to say that everyone has these problems at the start (:

Comment: If that "fixes your issue", please consider to accept the answer @Zomel Please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers